# Can I forget about IE6?

Tags: internet-explorer-6

I'm a consultant working on several websites and it has been asked that I make sure my work is compatible with IE6.

Since Microsoft advised not to use it anymore and that an average of 6% of the users are using IE6: can I advise my client to forget about IE6 ?

**Edit:**
The website is consumer oriented on the internet. I don't think IE6 is a strong requirement for my client just an old habit that's why I ask myself if it's a good thing to advise against it.

Comment: It depends on the target of the website. If the website is about the latest web technology, you may assume that noone is using IE6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends. Who is your target audience?

- Technical or non-technical?
- Business or consumer?
- Intranet or extranet?

How much effort is involved in making the site work in IE6? As much as I hate supporting a dying browser, I would avoid using features that prevent people with older browsers from using the site. Remember - some people are forced to use older browsers (because of corporate policy, etc.).

Comment: The last point (intranet / extranet) is indeed very important. Within a intranet, you've often control over the browsers so you do not have to worry about browser bug X.

Answer (score 7):

> You are a **consultant** working on
>   several websites and it has **been
>   asked** that you make sure your work is
>   compatible with IE6

If the **person that pays you** thinks IE6 needs to be supported, then it does!

What you think yourself, or what anyone else on stackoverflow thinks, is not important!

> "a requirement is anything that an
>   important person thinks is important"

Comment: Whilst I agree, part of being a consultant is advising the customer when you know better than they do rather than just blindly doing what you're told. They may have said "IE6" without really thinking about it - it's worth having a conversation with them at least. If they say yes they really do want it then you should give in.

Comment: Tell them that supporting IE6 will cost XYZ more. Then be happy that they do no longer want IE6 support. Just make clear that this will cost you quite some extra development time they'll have to pay for.

Answer (score 2):

You're free to forget about IE6 if you can afford to ignore those users.

I'm sure that the 6% is not uniformly distributed across all audiences.  If your application is targeted at an audience with a disproportionate IE6 holdout population you might have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ensuring that you support [progressive enhancement and gracefull degredation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550431/what-is-the-difference-between-progressive-enhancement-and-graceful-degradation) is important even if you don't support actively the browser.

With a bit of browser detection [suggest the user upgrade their browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377133/how-to-kindly-ask-your-users-to-upgrade-from-ie6) and educate them of the benefits of the latest generation of browsers.

If you get paid to do the work then do the job properly and your clients will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As the other respondents have said, it depends on your expected users. As a data point, see [UK Government sticks with ie6](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/1725908/uk-government-sticks-ie6)

Answer (score 0):

Depends, I've been developing sites for IE6 for a long time, and if you write proper CSS, you can get 1:1 with every browser. Same applies to javascript, if it's well written, it will work on IE6 too.

If you're sure that the audience which will browse the product is IE6 free, I'd say you're good to go about forgetting IE6. Plus, having a check for IE6 and then displaying a warning that the site is built for IE6+, and user needs to upgrade, is a good solution too (keeping in mind the little number of IE6 users).